# How to download uploaded files through a link in Django

Tags: django, file, download

I am uploading a file and saving it on a folder outside the media folder. I want to add a download link in a template to be able to download the file directly. I am not sure what to add in the URL, if I should add something

I tried this in the template it says URL not found

```html
<a href="{{data.tar_gif.url}}"> Download File</a>
```

views.py

```py
def uploaddata(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:

                if request.method == 'POST':
                        
                        form = uploadform(request.POST, request.FILES)
                        if form.is_valid():
                                form.save()
                                
                                return redirect('file_list')
                else:
                        form = uploadmetaform()
                        
                return render(request, 'uploaddata.html', {
                        'form': form
                })
        else:
                return render(request, 'home.html')
```

HTML page

```py
<tbody>
    {% for data in dataset %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{data.path_id}}</td>
        <td>{{ data.tar_gif }}</td>
        
        <td>
            <a href="{{data.document.url}}"> Download File</a>
                
            
            </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

models.py

```py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    Assigned_Group= models.CharField(max_length=500, choices=Group_choices, default='Please Select')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

#### upload file

```py
def nice_user_folder_upload(instance, filename):
    extension = filename.split(".")[-1]
    return (
        f"{instance.user_profile.Assigned_Group}/{filename}"
    )

class uploadmeta(models.Model):

    path = models.ForeignKey(Metadataform, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name='Username')
    

    document = models.FileField(upload_to=nice_user_folder_upload, verbose_name="Dataset") # validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['tar', 'zip'])]

   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.request.user
```

Comment: You have to write a view for the download process, that would return the file, you probably have to pass some info so that it knows which file should be downloaded. Do you understand the logic or you need to see some code?

Comment: Did you inspect the view to see the path of your anchor? Try to open that in a new tab to see is there any error? And if there is an error, please provide full traceback

Answer (score 6):

Actually simple way of doing it by using html **download** attribute 
the way you achieve this is by

```
<a href="{{data.document.url}}" download> Download File</a>
```

or you also use :

```
<a href="{{ data.document.url }}" download="{{ data.document.url }}"> Download File</a>
```

Comment: it says -- File not found (the file is in the path)

Comment: @user11603936  I think its somethings wrong with your form or models .. can you share your models.py code for better understanding

Comment: I Think its the problem of `def nice_user_folder_upload` Try once with `upload_to='your_folder/'`  And also check whether the file upload is uploading in file ..

Comment: i get the same error, this is nothing to do with routing the files i guess. should i add some link in the url?

Comment: No you need to add any link in url ..i am not sure whats wrong with your code ..did you try to upload file from django admin and try to download the same file from template ?   .. And also i found something in models.py in `class uploadmeta` i donno why you have used `def __str__(self):
        return self.request.user` I probably think it should be `def __str__(self):
        return self.user_profile.user`..

Comment: whoa is that easy i thought i would have to something hard but just use download and it worked. Thanks Man

Answer (score 4):

1.settings.py:

```
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
#Media
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

2.urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

3.in template:

```
<a href="{{ file.url }}" download>Download File.</a>
```

## Work and test in django >=3

for more detail use this link:
https://youtu.be/MpDZ34mEJ5Y

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post:
[How to serve downloadable files using Django (Chris Gregori) ?](https://ednsquare.com/question/how-to-serve-downloadable-files-using-django------9lAMsr)

Maybe a better way to not expose the path of the files, even the names if you do want to do that. I do not like the idea to show the structure of the paths to users. Other things you can accomplish with this is to validate who can download the files if you check the request.user with your database for every file is served, and it is pretty simple.

Basically, the publication refers to using the xsendfile module so django generates the path to the file (or the file itself), but the actual file serving is handled by Apache/Lighttpd. Once you've set up mod_xsendfile, integrating with your view takes a few lines of code:"

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str

response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/force-download') # mimetype is replaced by content_type for django 1.7
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(file_name)

response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(path_to_file)
# It's usually a good idea to set the 'Content-Length' header too.
# You can also set any other required headers: Cache-Control, etc.
return response
```

As I said before, I do not like the idea of having published the path to the file.

With this pointer to the information, you can research and get this working.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: This is link-only, apart from recommending it, doubting methods....

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Hello Yunnosch, Ok, let me updated with information. I thought that copying and paste information from other sources was duplicating the information on the net. I take your comment, thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: Done. Thank you.